# Conversion between BGR to YCrCb and back to BGR

Tags: opencv

I have tried to convert from BGR to YCrCb to increase the luminance and convert it back to BGR

cvSplit(luma, y, cr, cb, 0); << splitting does not need in order right?

...do something about luminance component

cvMerge(temp_y, cr, cb, 0, luma); << What is the proper order of luminance, Cr and Cb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert between different color spaces you need to use [cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cvtColor). To get from BGR to YCC, you should to pass the parameter `CV_BGR2YCrCb` (and to go back again is `CV_YCrCb2BGR`). The correct usage is:

```
cvtColor(src, dest, CV_BGR2YCrCb)
```

Where `src` is your source frame, and `dest` will be your processed frame (you could just put `src` here for it to do the change in place).

`cvSplit` isn't what you need for this, as it just splits a multi channel array into several single channel arrays (its components). So if you had a BGR frame of video, `cvSplit` can give you just the B, G, R channels in isolation.

If you want to process the Y channel in isolation you could convert color space, and then split and then merge back, like this:

```
cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2YCrCb)
cvSplit(frame, Y, Cr, Cb, NULL)
#Process the Y channel here.
cvMerge(Y, Cr, Cb, NULL, frame)
cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_YCrCb2BGR)
```

If you just want to increase the brightness of the image, a simpler way (you don't need to use luminance) is to add a scaler to each channel:

```
cvAddS(frame, cvScalar(30,30,30), frame)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does cvSplit BGR need to be in order? And I need to do something on the luminance therefore i convert from BGR2YCrCb then use cvSplit after that I need to use cvMerge to merge the luminance(already done something on the luminance), Cr and Cb back. After merge will convert back to BGR using YCrCb2BGR. Therefore, I have problem in determining the proper order of merging the luminance,Cr and Cb. Should it be:
>> cvMerge(temp_y, cr, cb, 0, luma) or
>> cvMerge(temp_y, cb, cr, 0, luma)
because both give different output image.

Comment: @Mizuki Kai - The order is important. Without seeing your code I don't know what you are doing wrong. But I've updated my answer to illustrate you could do things. Also the [documentarion](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#Split) for opencv is really good, and worth consulting.

Comment: That's mean, since we know openCV uses BGR2YCrCb then the order should be this way cvMerge(Y, Cr, Cb, NULL, frame); just follow the order is sufficient.Am I right?

Comment: @Mizuki Kai - No meanness intended! Yes, stick to the same order, and it should be fine. :)